# scanf("%d",a) with a "while" grammar bypass the scanf

Tags: c, switch-statement, scanf

if there is no initialization ("mod=0") , this code go infinite loop.
I can't understand why this code go loop, even if I used getchar();
to erase the buffer.
when I typed "1" first, and typed "a" next, there goes an infinite loop.
Can anybody help me with understanding this situation?

```
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int mod = 0;
    int val = 0;
    do {    
        printf("\t-----------------------------\n");
        printf("\t|%5s %5s %5s %5s|\n", "1.create", "2.modify", "3.print", "4.quit");
        printf("\t|%15s","Input command  : ");
        scanf("%d", &mod);
        printf("\t-----------------------------\n");
        switch (mod){
        case 1:     random();           val++;      break;
        case 2:     if(val != 0) { modify();    break; }
        case 3:     if(val != 0) { print();     break; }
        default:    getchar(); printf("\tUnknown Command!! Retry!! \n");    break;
        }
    } while (mod != 4);
}
```

I compiled this code with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Put a `print` statement right after the `scanf` just to verify things are what you expect, or attach a debugger.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you're entering `char` while the variable is `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you input `a`, it's an invalid input for `mod` as `scanf()` expects an `int` for `%d`. So it's *not* read into `mod`. So the `mod` is left with the value of `mod` inputted in the previous iteration.

And the reason it goes in an infinite loop is because `scanf()` doesn't discard the invalid input. So repeatedly attempts to read `a` and fails and loop goes on.

Check the return value of `scanf()` and discard any invalid input(s).
`scanf()` is notoriously bad for reading user input and proper handling input failures is generally harder using it.

A better approach is to read a *line* input using [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) and then parse it using [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

```
do {
    ...

    printf("\t|%15s","Input command  : ");

    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
    char *p = strchr(line, '\n');
    if(p) *p = 0; /* remove tailing newline, if present */
    if( sscanf(line, "%d", &mod) != 1) {
       printf("Invalid input\n");
       continue;
    }

    printf("\t-----------------------------\n");
    ....

   }while (mod != 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, that once you typed in an number, which is a valid menu option, the variable mod is always equal to the same number, that was input during the first time you entered it, if you enter a wrong input the second time. This behavior comes from the fact, that

```
scanf(%d, &mod);
```

tries to read an integer, but as you entered an 'a' as a second option for example, the input is not able to read an integer from your Standard input. So it will not enter the default case of your switch method, as the variable mod is equal to the input from the first valid input you entered.